# VScode windows 10 ,"set" not working in the terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I got an issue ..
I was temping to type like : set NODE_ENV=production  ; set NODE_ENV=development ;But it dosn't work .. I had reinstall the vscode ,and it doesn't work neighter ... What's more ,it dosen't throw any error .. I have no idea how to debug it .

Version: 1.54.1 (user setup)
Commit: f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8
Date: 2021-03-04T22:38:31.419Z
Electron: 11.3.0
Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
Node.js: 12.18.3
V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363

Anyone can help ? Thanks so much !!

Comment: What does *not working* mean? You've not described a problem here.

Comment: Not working : for instance ,I wanted to set the NODE_ENV=production ; however ,the environment always development ..